# Using local variables to search for procedure names in sys.procedures (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, object, procedure, local-variables

I want to run a series of queries (same query really) on a few databases in a given server where I only change the table name being looked up.

```
USE database 
Go

SELECT name
FROM   sys.procedures
WHERE  Object_definition(object_id) LIKE '%value%'
```

there are about 5 servers, with 10 databases on average to search. I don't want to copy and past the string each time. I want to declare a @string and update it once.

```
DECLARE @string_lookup NVARCHAR(MAX) = '%stringtolookup%'
```

I've tried it two ways and I can't get it to work. This is what I've tried:

option 1:

```
DECLARE @string_lookup NVARCHAR(MAX) = '%stringtolookup%'

Exec ('SELECT name FROM sys.procedures WHERE Object_definition(object_id) LIKE ' + @string_lookup)
```

option 2:

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(100) ,@SQL NVARCHAR(max) = ''

SET @var = '%stringtolookup%'
SET @sql = 'select name From sys.procedures WHERE  Object_definition(object_id) LIKE ' + @var

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

Neither seem to work. I've found a few tickets posted about how to declare @variable, and use it part of the USE statement to change the database name but that I don't need what I need is to modify a procedure name and search it across each database without a series of outputs.

I get the following error messages:

```
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
Must declare the scalar variable "@string_lookup".
```

There was a comment provided below that suggested i print the data because im missing single quotes, thank you that did fix a part of the error however this is the code now and it still doesn't work:

```
DECLARE @string_lookup VARCHAR(100) = '%web_app%'
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max) = ''
SET @sql = 'select name From sys.procedures WHERE  Object_definition(object_id) LIKE ''' + @var + ''''

USE db1
Go
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL

USE db2
Go
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL

USE db3
Go
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

Comment: For the databases on a single instance this is fairly simple. We can leverage sys.databases and some dynamic sql easily. However, to do this on multiple servers means you either have to copy and paste the same string for a single server to each server, or you need to have linked servers created for every remote server you want to search.

Comment: Same server, different databases on that server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leveraging sys.databases you can use dynamic sql here to avoid the dreaded loop. There are additional comments in the code to help provide contextual understanding.

```
DECLARE @string_lookup VARCHAR(100) = '%web_app%'
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'select ''' + quotename(db.name) + ''' as DatabaseName, name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS from ' + quotename(db.name) + '.sys.procedures where Object_definition(object_id) LIKE ''' + @string_lookup + ''' UNION ALL '
from sys.databases db
where db.state_desc = 'ONLINE' --exclude OFFLINE databases
--you could include any other predicates here to eliminate any other databases


select @SQL = left(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 10)

select @SQL --uncomment the next line when you are comfortable the dynamic sql is correct
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: This is great, but is there a way to do this without union-ing all the data. The  output set comes back as one piece of information which is great in general but i need to know where (in what database the procedures exist).

Comment: So include the data base name as another column.

Answer (score 1):

If you print out your SQL first, you can see where the error is.
You are missing single quotes around the string.

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(100) ,@SQL NVARCHAR(max) = ''

SET @var = '%stringtolookup%'
SET @sql = 'select name From sys.procedures WHERE  Object_definition(object_id) LIKE ''' + @var + ''''
print @sql

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

Comment: While this does work there is a problem, I have to recreate each declaration of `@var` and `@sql` for each  use databasename go` statement. Because it complains I need a scalar variable for `@var` and doesn't work

Comment: `DECLARE @string_lookup VARCHAR(100) = '%web_app%'
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max) = ''
SET @sql = 'select name From sys.procedures WHERE  Object_definition(object_id) LIKE ''' + @var + ''''

USE db1
Go
 
 EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL

USE db2
Go

 EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL` 
generates a whole bunch of errors stating that i have to declare scalar variables.

Answer (score 0):

Variables can be set on the line they are declared, and you don't need dynamic SQL for this.

```
declare @var varchar(100) = '%stringtolookup%'

select name
From sys.procedures 
WHERE  object_definition(object_id) LIKE @var
```

Comment: I should have added I get the following error message: 
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
Must declare the scalar variable "@string_lookup". or @var it doesn't matter what i name my variable

Comment: Please add some text to explain your answer